# Storing temporary files

Tags: macos, file, temporary

I would like to generate some temporary files in the course of my application.  Specifically, I'm using AVAudioRecorder to record a file that I, upon stopping the recording, would like to load and edit/process.  My question is:

What is the appropriate standard place to create temporary files.  Is there some generally accepted approach to this for Mac or for iPad programming in general?  I don't want to simply create a directory and write files into it if there is a proper protocol to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is actually a lot more complicated then one might assume. One cannot necessarily just use NSTemporaryDirectory and be done. I cocoadev.com has some good pages on this topic and I would suggest that you study them yourself and determine what will work best for your circumstance.

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTemporaryDirectory

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?GettingTemporaryFolderOnSpecificVolume

Comment: Both of these links are dead.

Answer (score 1):

The usual place for applications to store temporary data is `/var/tmp`. You could also use `/tmp` but this directory is for system-generated temporary files and anything in `/tmp` is deleted when the machine reboots.

Answer (score 1):

What I found was that according to the iOS Application Programming Guide, I am supposed to query for the appropriate temporary folder for my application via NSTemporaryDirectory().  I tried this and it returned a folder within the /var directory, in my case '/var/folders/pQ/pQ+ZqZCSHWSIHftcbIo57U+++TI/-Tmp-/'.

Answer (score 0):

`/tmp` or `/usr/tmp` are the usual places to store temporary files in Unix (which Mac OS X and iOS are).